# url dando erro 404 quando adiciono pagina

Tags: php, sql, html, phtml

boa tarde galera, estou com uma baita "dor de cabeça" aqui no trampo, estou tentando adicionar pagina num site aqui, porém não esta funcionando: tenho que adiocionar uma url assim: /novapagina sem extensão, porem no arquivo htacces está deste jeito, e eu não estou conseguindo solucionar:

obs: cada arquivo de phtml está dentro de uma pasta, e a url chama pelo nome da pasta e não do arquivo

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beta2018.emagrecentro\.com.br
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://emagrecentro.com.br/$1 [R=permanent,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.emagrecentro\.com.br
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://emagrecentro.com.br/$1 [R=permanent,L]

# COM SSL
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?emagrecentro\.com.br [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://emagrecentro.com.br/$1 [R=permanent,L]


# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```